# SQL select into syntax

Tags: sql, select, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a temporary table with a select into statement in a stored procedure as follows:

```
SELECT *
INTO #GENEALOGY
FROM
( 
SELECT field1, field2, 
    (SELECT fieldA from tableY WHERE...) as field3,
    (SELECT fieldB from tableY WHERE...) as field4
FROM table
WHERE condition
)
```

Any command I type after this closing bracket fails the syntax check (such as another SELECT statement). 
I've tried putting BEGIN and END before and after the whole statement and then starting my next command.
I've tried adding

```
AS tablename
```

after the closing bracket and then the next statement but it doesn't like that either

I've tried removing the # but same problem.

I actually need to run a WHILE loop after this and INSERT more records into the same table.

What am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code seems to be product specific.)

Comment: Taking a guess at this being SQL Server, you will need the alias after `)` but this is otherwise correct.  If it is SQL Server and the alias didn't solve your problem, it is something else in your proc that isn't shown here.  What is the error message?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: hi all sorry about the delay in replying and thanks for the comments.

Comment: yes it is SQL Server. there's no actual error message as i'm not in a position to run the procedure yet. i'm just going by the red squiggly line under the next verb which seems to be saying my syntax is wrong. maybe i shouldn't worry about that and just crack on

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, why are you using a subquery?

```
SELECT field1, field2, 
    (SELECT fieldA from tableY WHERE...) as field3,
    (SELECT fieldB from tableY WHERE...) as field4
INTO #GENEAOLOGY
FROM table
WHERE condition;
```

The structure of your query is ok.  You should include a semi-colon at the end, if this is in a programming block.  I assume `table` is a real name and that the other parts of the query are syntactically correct.

Comment: i guess i could translate all the sub select statements into the main query but it seemed a bit of a pain at the time - i needed to link to the same table a couple of times with different links and it was just easier to write a few sub queries. maybe hits the performance i don't know but its only returning one field from one record each time . yes table was just for the post and yes the rest of the query is ok. think i'm just going to ignore the syntax checker and finish it off and run it and see

Comment: hi Gordon, do you know the performance difference between say using 6 joins in a single SELECT as opposed to six separate selects (or six subqueries i suppose). In each case i'd only be returning 1 record from the table. thanks

Comment: @jfly62 . . . There are no general rules, but there is no reason to avoid a query with six joins.  Complex queries are why SQL exists.

Answer (score 0):

What does the error mention? If you run this in SSMS more than once, the second time the temp table already exists and could be an error.

You said an alias was not enough, but this is a right sentence:

```
SELECT *
INTO #GENEALOGY
FROM
( 
SELECT field1, field2, 
    (SELECT fieldA from tableY WHERE...) as field3,
    (SELECT fieldB from tableY WHERE...) as field4
FROM table
WHERE condition
) as TableNameAlias
```

Comment: yeah i realise you can only select into a temp table once, tks. i've not actually run it all. only going by the syntax checker  - as mentioned in last comment above

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the help

in the end I changed to an INSERT INTO rather than a SELECT INTO because
a) i needed to do 2 different select queries to get the data i need  (1 for the first record and a 2nd for all subsequent records) and the second query would have had to be an INSERT anyway
b) and i wasn't sure how long sql server would keep the temp table open if i was calling the procedure from a crystal report

so i created a fixed table, use SELECT INTO and just delete all records as first line of my sp to clear out unwanted data

ta!